# How to set up live url for Java spring boot websocket client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I've seen dozens of tutorials for how to write a websocket, but in all of these tutorials the websocket runs on `localhost`. I wrote a Java Spring boot websocket client code, and it does work on localhost:8080. I tested it by running from IntelliJ as well as running as a Windows service.

This is my `registerWebSocketHandlers` method from the `WebSocketConfig` class:

```
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) { 
  webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/websocket").setHandshakeHandler(new 
  DefaultHandshakeHandler(new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy()));
}
```

However, what I can't understand - how to link a websocket to a particular, live url ?
I can get it work on `localhost:8080/websocket` (my app side client connects successfully), but how to make it work on `https://mywebsite.com/websocket` ? How to link this **/websocket** to my url?

I'll appreciate your suggestions and ideas.

Comment: it depends - if you just want to simulate the "live" behaviour locally, then you need to edit hosts file and add entry there in order to redirect your home address to your website (sth like "127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com".
You can also configure your private dns server.
If you want to really go live, it will take way more than that.

Comment: @CaptainAye thank you for your response. By any chance, are you aware of any tutorials/instructions online  for "really" going live?

Comment: You need to buy a domain first. To understand how it works, you can read this pages
https://www.namecheap.com/guru-guides/how-to-host-a-website-in-2021-comprehensive-guide-for-newbies/
https://medium.com/notes-from-the-classroom/basic-guide-to-get-a-domain-set-up-web-hosting-and-upload-your-first-website-via-ftp-ecc7e5e4d557

I would recommend using managed services for you. One of the well known is heroku.
It has a free tier with which you can try it out in the begining, and if you need more, you can extend.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java

Comment: I have a purchased domain, and it should be supporting websockets. I just don't know how to work with the web part. Thank you, I'll check this out!